# Populate select onCLick and then display

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have an empty HTML select element. onClick I remove all options, do a synchronous AJAX call to get new options, remove the existing options, and finally add the new options returned by the AJAX call. This works as expected. When the select box opens it shows the populated options.

However, if I again click the select box when it already has options populated the select box opens displaying the options present before function `retrieveValues` removes and adds options.

```
<select id="YearId"></select>

$("#YearId").click(function () { retrieveValues($(this)) });

function retrieveValues(selectBox) {
    // This function does an synchronous jQuery Ajax call.
    // On success we remove all options from `selectBox` and add new entries.
}
```

I've changed the `click` handler to instead by `focus` which seems to work, but is this a good solution? I suspect it might be a race condition between the focus and click events?

Comment: well that's a normal behavior for a select to open it's options on click, you need to remove the options first and then retrieve the new ones

Comment: or try a `ev.preventDefault()` before `retrieve`

Comment: I want the select to open and show it's options, but I want it to show the options populated by the function called during the `onClick` event. I could use preventDefault, but after the Ajax call causes the select to be populated with new options I want the select box to be rendered open. But as mentioned the `focus` handler does seem to do the right thing. I just wonder if there is a race or timing condition.

Comment: Not really understand what  you mean by race or timing condition -> which on it's triggered first, click or focus?

Comment: Is the onFocus event guaranteed to be called and completed before the onClick event? If the onFocus event is handled asychronously then the onClick event might render the select element before onFocus has a chance to do the Ajax call and re-populate the select element.

Comment: focus is after click as far as I know